# Ajax functionality not being called under wordpress plugin

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I am trying to build a wordpress plugin to provide a filter form, it fetches the data from the database using Ajax from the input sent by users. I am trying to submit the form via Ajax.

[image: Plugin File Structure]

I doubt whether placing of an AJAX call function, **form_ajax_process_request()** under **ajax-process-form.js** is right or not?

Here is the **ajax-process-form.js** code

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
jQuery('HCS-quicksearchForm').bind('submit', function() {

var data = {
    action: 'form_response',
    post_var: 'this will be echoed back'
};
console.log(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl);
$.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
return false;
});
});

<?php 
    function form_ajax_process_request() {
        if( isset( $_POST["post_var"] ) ) {
            $response = $_POST["post_var"];
            echo $response;
            die();
        }
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_form_response','form_ajax_process_request');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_form_response','form_ajax_process_request');
?>
```

Form UI **schoolform_view.php** code

```
<?php
    echo '<fieldset>';
    echo'<div id="HCS-quicksearch" class="HCS-quicksearchWrapper">';
    echo'<form id="HCS-quicksearchForm" class="hcs-school-form" action="" method="POST">';      
    echo '<div id="HCS-qsCityWrap" class="HCS-qsFieldWrap">';
    global $wpdb;
    $city_results = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * from wp_gj73yj2g8h_hillsborough_county_cities;"        );
    echo '<select id="city_id HCS-qsCity" name="city_name" class="HCS-qsInput HCS-qsSelectInput">';
    echo '<option value="">Choose a City</option>';
    foreach ( $city_results as $result ) {
    echo '<option>'.$result->city_name.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<input id="HCS-qsSubmit" class="HCS-qsInput HCS-qsButtonInput" type="submit" name="form-submitted" value="Search">';      
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</fieldset>';
?>
```

plugin core school_core.php code

```
    <?
 /*
Plugin Name: Hillsborough County Homes By School Properties
Plugin URI: http://accessrealtytampa.com
Description: Search For Homes By School Name, Ranking and other Features
Version:0.1.0
Author: Himani Lotia

*/
define( 'HCS_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )   );
define( 'HCS_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'HCS_VERSION', '0.1.0'                  );

add_action('init', 'register_script');
function register_script() {
    wp_register_style( 'hcs-style', HCS_URL . '/assets/css/hcsstyle.css', FALSE, HCS_VERSION, 'all' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');

function enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('hcs-style');
}

function ajax_load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script("ajax-process-form", HCS_URL. 'ajax-process-form.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script ( 'ajax-process-form', 'the_ajax_script', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url(admin-ajax.php ) ) );
}

add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'ajax_load_scripts');

function schoolform() {

    enqueue_style();
     $saved_data =  get_option('save_plugin_settings');
     $saved_data = $saved_data ? unserialize($saved_data) : null ;

     include_once(HCS_PATH . '/schoolform_view.php');
}


function hcs_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    schoolform();
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('hcs_school_filter','hcs_shortcode');
?>
```

In my google chrome console, ajax-process-form.js is present under  but in console log it is displaying a Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error comes from your js file that is containing php code. You don't need this part to be in the js file and need to be in a php file.

```
<?php 
function form_ajax_process_request() {
    if( isset( $_POST["post_var"] ) ) {
        $response = $_POST["post_var"];
        echo $response;
        die();
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_form_response','form_ajax_process_request');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_form_response','form_ajax_process_request');
?>
```

This part need to be in `school_core.php` (without `<?php and ?>`).

Comment: Yet, not able to make this work.